# Does TypeScript have Extensions like Kotlin?

Tags: typescript

Kotlin has feature called [Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), that allows you to "extend" any type (including built-in types) without actually extending it.

For example:

```
function Array<T>.swap(i1: number, i2: number) {
    let tmp = this[i1]
    this[i1] = this[i2]
    this[i2] = tmp
}

let list = [1, 2, 3]
list.swap(0, 2)
console.log(list) // => 3, 2, 1
```

The fun part is that, unlike normal extending of the base types, this approach **does not change the Array or its prototype chain**.

The generated JS code will be something like:

```
function _array_extensions_swap(i1, i2) {
    let tmp = this[i1]
    this[i1] = this[i2]
    this[i2] = tmp
}

let list = [1, 2, 3]
_array_extensions_swap(list, 0, 2)
console.log(list) // => 3, 2, 1
```

I wonder if it's possible to do the same in TypeScript, or if there are plans to support that in the future?

Comment: I would guess that it is not in the plans, it seems to deviate too much from JavaScript. TypeScript is supposed to remain relatively close to JavaScript in the hope that JavaScript will take its features in the future. I think your question should be: will JavaScript offer this?

Answer (score -2):

There's no such thing, and I doubt that it will come in the future, the main reason for that is that there's no reason for this.
In compiled languages like kotlin you can not simply add new properties to existing instances, but in javascript (and therefor with typescript aswell) you can simply do:

```
let list = [1, 2, 3] as number[] & { swap(i1: number, i2: number): void };
list.swap = function (i1: number, i2: number) {
    let tmp = this[i1]
    this[i1] = this[i2]
    this[i2] = tmp;
}

list.swap(0, 2);
console.log(list); // [3, 2, 1]
```

You can create a factory function to extend existing lists:

```
function extend<T>(list: T[]): T[] & { swap(i1: number, i2: number): void } {
    (list as T[] & { swap(i1: number, i2: number): void }).swap = function (i1: number, i2: number) {
        let tmp = this[i1]
        this[i1] = this[i2]
        this[i2] = tmp;
    }

    return list as T[] & { swap(i1: number, i2: number): void };
}

let list = extend([1, 2, 3]);
list.swap(0, 2);
console.log(list); // [3, 2, 1]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20GTree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20createNode(name%3A%20string)%3A%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GNodeImpl(name)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GNodeImpl%20implements%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D#src=function%20extend%3CT%3E(list%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D).swap%20%3D%20function%20(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20this%5Bi1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi1%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bi2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi2%5D%20%3D%20tmp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20extend(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0Alist.swap(0%2C%202)%3B%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B3%2C%202%2C%201%5D))

Comment: How do you plan to actually use it? Are you going to add 10-20 such functions to every instance of array in your code? And also for String.isBlank / isPresent / reverse etc...

Comment: Check my revised answer. The `extend` function can add what ever you want to the instances

Comment: That's a well known approach with huge disadvantage. It has terrible performance (you have to store bunch of funcs on every created object), and also quite verbose with the need to explicitly extend every Array/String and others.

Comment: If you'd like to choose that path, there's a better option - introduce `class MyArray extend Array` and use it instead. No need to store bunch of functions on every objects, but still inconvenient and verbose.

Comment: It seemed from your question that you want to avoid extending or changing the prototype. There are ways to make this better like declaring the functions and then just assign a reference to them in each instance, but the point was that in javascript you can change the instance and introduce new properties unlike with kotlin.